# How to spread out alignment for a zstack to be top and bottom?

Tags: swiftui

Suppose I have two images where I want to align one on the top and one on the bottom.  I tried the below and a couple other ways but the heart never aligns to the bottom.

```
ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .top)) {

     Image(systemName: "heart")

     Image(systemName: "heart")
           .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.bottom) { d in d[.bottom] + 8 }    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        
        ZStack
        {

            VStack
            {
                Image(systemName: "heart").padding()

                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "heart").padding()
                   
                
            } .foregroundColor(Color.red).font(Font.title.bold())
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

[image]